# Dynamic input in a callback function

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I found this app in dash that had a filter for each column in the bottom of the column for a specific dataframe, I tried to modify it to make it so that the filters are created depending on the dataframe. The filters are been created but I can't get it to update de dataframe to the filtered version after putting the filters.
This is the code:

```
from dash import Dash, dash_table, dcc, html, Input, Output, callback, State
import pandas as pd
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
# Need to use Python 3.8 or higher and Dash 2.2.0 or higher
dates = ['datetime64[ns, tz]']
boolean = ['bool', 'BooleanDtype']
strings = ['object', 'StringDtype']
floats = ['float64', 'float32', 'float16']
ints = ['int32', 'int16', 'int8', 'UInt64', 'int64', 'UInt32', 'UInt16', 'UInt8', 'UInt64Dtype']
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminder2007.csv')
df = df[['continent', 'country', 'pop', 'lifeExp']]

def filter(column):
    type = str(df[column].dtype)
    if type in ints:
        return  dcc.Slider(df[column].min(), df[column].max(), 1, marks={str(df[column].max()):str(df[column].max())}, value=df[column].min(),
                                   tooltip={"placement": "bottom", "always_visible": True})
    elif type in floats:
        return  dcc.Slider(df[column].min(), df[column].max(), 0.5, marks={str(df[column].max()):str(df[column].max())}, value=df[column].min(),
                                   tooltip={"placement": "bottom", "always_visible": True})
    elif type in strings:
        return  dcc.Dropdown([x for x in sorted(df[column].unique())], multi=True)

    elif type in boolean:
        return dcc.Dropdown([x for x in sorted(df[column].unique())], multi=False)

        
filters = [filter(col) for col in df.columns]
input_component_mapping = {col: filter(col) for col in df.columns}

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])


app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dcc.Markdown('# DataTable Tips and Tricks', style={'textAlign':'center'}),

    dbc.Label("Show number of rows"),
    row_drop := dcc.Dropdown(value=10, clearable=False, style={'width':'35%'},
                             options=[10, 25, 50, 100]),

    my_table := dash_table.DataTable(
        columns=[
            {'name': 'Continent', 'id': 'continent', 'type': 'numeric'},
            {'name': 'Country', 'id': 'country', 'type': 'text'},
            {'name': 'Population', 'id': 'pop', 'type': 'numeric'},
            {'name': 'Life Expectancy', 'id': 'lifeExp', 'type': 'numeric'}
        ],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        filter_action='native',
        page_size=10,

        style_data={
            'width': '150px', 'minWidth': '150px', 'maxWidth': '150px',
            'overflow': 'hidden',
            'textOverflow': 'ellipsis',
        }
    ),
    dbc.Row(children=[
            dbc.Col(
                input_component_mapping[col],
                width=3,
                id=f"{col}-filter"  # Use the column name as the ID
            ) for col in df.columns
        ], justify="between", className='mt-3 mb-4'),

])
# Create a list of Input components dynamically
inputIds = [Input(f"{col}-filter", 'value') for col in df.columns]
print(inputIds)
@callback(
    [Output(my_table, 'data')],
    inputsIds
)
def update_dropdown_options(*input_states):
    dff = df.copy()
    print(input_states)
    for i, (col, state) in enumerate(zip(df.columns, input_states)):
        type = str(df[col].dtype)
        print(col, state)
        if type in ints or type in floats:
            print("is in")
            # Convert state to float to ensure proper comparison
            state = float(state)
            dff = dff[(dff[col] >= state) & (dff[col] <= df[col].max())]
        
        if type in strings:
            if state:
                dff = dff[dff[col].isin(state)]
        
        if type in boolean:
            dff = dff[dff[col] == state]

    return dff.to_dict('records')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8001)
```

The problem is for sure in the callback function because when I print the Input_states its just a None list.